# Changing storage directory in cassandra database while there are already data in it

Tags: cassandra, directory, local-storage

I have a cassandra cluster with 16 nodes and my database has ~5000 rows of data. The storage location is the default one: /var/lib/cassandra/data. I want to change the location to /home/ubuntu/cassandradata where cassandradata is a symbolic link to a location with more space. My questions are:

1) Is it enough if I just change the location "data_file_directories" in cassandra.yaml file?

2) If I change the location, what will happen to the data already stored in the database? Will they be automatically transfered to the new location? Do I have to manually copy them or is it better to use COPY FROM/TO (meaning export them before I change the location and import them after I change the location)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is what you want to do:

1. Shut down DSE/Cassandra
2. Move the existing data to the new directory
3. Change the data directory in the cassandra.yaml
4. Start DSE/Cassandra up

That should do it.

Comment: Can you please tell me a bit more about the 2? Copy paste the whole ../cassandra/data folder in the new location or just the folder of the keyspace(which is inside the ../cassandra/data)??

Comment: @Des0lat0r you would need to copy the entire data directory (all keyspaces) to the new location.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! So, to be clear I have to copy to the new location, in every node, all the contents of /var/lib/cassandra/data: "mydb", "system",  "system_auth",  "system_distributed",  "system_schema",  "system_traces"??

Comment: Also, should I do a "nodetool flush" before moving the contents of "/var/lib/cassandra/data" folder??

Comment: Done successfully! Thank you both very much!